# PHP date returning wrong Month on subtracting one month

Tags: php, date

Current Date is 29th March 2017

When I subtract 2 months using PHP and I get `January`

```
$prevmonth = date('M', strtotime('-2 months'));
echo $prevmonth;
```

But when I subtract 1 month it gives `March`

```
$prevmonth = date('M', strtotime('-1 months'));
echo $prevmonth;
```

Comment: because there isn't a 29th day in Februrary

Comment: @JohnConde: At least not this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` uses 30 day months and there are only 28 in days in February (this year) so will not yield a valid date in February.  You could use the current day `d` or `j` and subtract that which will always put you in the previous month (`-29 days`):

```
$prevmonth = date('M', strtotime('-' . date('d') . ' days'));
```

This will get `December` from `January` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As covered in the comments, there's no 29th Feb.

29th Feb becomes 1st March.

You may be better to get the current month number, -1 from it, and then get the textual representation.

```
$prevMonth = date('n') - 1;
$prevMonthText = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $prevMonth, 10));
```

Or, you could use `DateTime` if your PHP version allows (it should).

```
$prevMonth = date('n') - 1;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $prevMonth);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('M'); // March
```

The only issue with this, that you might have spotted, is January will never return December. A quick ternary statement will catch that.

```
$prevMonth = ((date('n') - 1) < 1) ? 12 : date('n') - 1;
```