# Rest the month and I keep giving the same month with Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Until yesterday it worked perfectly showed me February and January, the two previous months but now it is showing me March and January:

[image: Carbon]

This is the date of my computer recently:

[image: now]

This is the code:

[image: code]
[image: code2]

I do not understand what is happening if some information is missing or they need something else I can provide it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date returning wrong Month on subtracting one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097411/php-date-returning-wrong-month-on-subtracting-one-month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subtracting a month from the 29th of March, you would expect to get the 29th of February, which does not exist. So, PHP compensates this by counting the extra days. This way, the date becomes the 1st of march.

To avoid this problem, use the carbon constructor and instruct it to get the last month:

```
$lastMonth = new Carbon('first day of last month');
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this topic in PHP

Comment: If I arrive a month with 31 days, does it still work? 
for example 03-31-2019 would you return 03-01-2019?

Comment: Indeed, this would be a problem, I have update my answer because of this. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how could you do with that same type of syntax the month before the previous month? basically get the previous month from the previous