# "Monthbar" generated in php shows march two times

Tags: php, wordpress

I built a monthbar for tribe events in PHP. It worked quite well until yesterday: the bar shows March two times now and it seems like there was no February in 2020 - sorry for that :)

This is wat it looks like on my website:

JUL AUG SEP OKT NOV DEZ JAN **MRZ** MRZ APR MAI JUN

I checked the code - but I dont see a prob here and it worked quite well until yesterday. I deleted all Worpdress caches.

```
<?php

//domain:
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// find out the path to the current file:
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
// find out the QueryString:
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// put it all together:
//$url = "https://" . $domain . $path . "?" . $queryString;
// An alternative way is to use REQUEST_URI instead of both
// SCRIPT_NAME and QUERY_STRING, if you don't need them seperate:
$url = "http://" . $domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//echo $url;
//$url = "http://docks.5536188857701.hostingkunde.de/events/list/";
//Ende aktuelle Domain finden 

        $currentmonth = date_i18n('M'); //localization date_i18n
        echo "<ul id='my-month-bar'>";
        for ( $i = 0; $i <= 11 ; $i++ )
            {
            $current_ym = date_i18n('Y-m',strtotime("+$i months"));
            $m = date_i18n('M',strtotime("+$i months")); 
//localization date_i18n
            $title = date_i18n('Y-m' . "-01",strtotime("+$i months"));
            $y = date_i18n('Y',strtotime("+$i months"));
            $query = $url;
            $my_mo = get_query_var('tribe-bar-date');
            $new_query = add_query_arg( array(
            'tribe-bar-date' => $title,
            ), $query );
            if ($my_mo == $current_ym){
            echo "<li><a title='Veranstaltungen im $m' rel='nofollow' id='my-monthbar-act' href='$new_query'> $m </a></li>"; 
//if is current month
            }else{
            echo "<li><a title='Veranstaltungen im $m' rel='nofollow' id='my-monthbar' href='$new_query'> $m </a></li>";
            }}
            echo "</ul>";
        ?></div>
```

Having Feb 2020 back would be great!

Comment: Have it output the full date and not only the month, then it should become more easily apparent what goes wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date returning wrong Month on subtracting one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097411/php-date-returning-wrong-month-on-subtracting-one-month)

Comment: @misorude, thanks! Good point - will try that on my staging page.
Its quite possible those topics (like the one you just linked) are related. I thought about that when I saw only "Feb" was missing. But it worked until yesterday - so I dont think it is in a way related to the code itself?

Comment: Well we are at the 29th/30th “barrier” right now, so it is possible that this appeared to work up until now for the “smaller” days in July. If you had this running in June already, you probably would have had the same problem then though towards the end of the month.

Comment: @misorude - you make me believe. :D

Comment: @misorude. Strange things are happeing now. It says: 
JUL AUG OKT OKT DEZ DEZ JAN MRZ MRZ MAI MAI JUL

Comment: So, this is related as Jul has 31 days but Okt has 30.

Comment: @misorude - I managed to get the correct month list. But I dont know how to get the current year-month combo for my url. Could you help me with this?
'for($i = $todaysmonth; $i <= $todaysmonth+11; $i++){
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i);
   $monthName = $dateObj->format('M');
 $month = $dateObj->format('m');'
I can get Jan1970 out of it, but not Jan2019 or 2019-07-01.

Comment: The year defaults to 1970 if you only specify the month. Try something like `Y-m` as format specifier, and `2019-6` as the value to parse.

Comment: Okay @misorude, thx! If I specify something like 2019-06, is this date fixed as reference date or is this s reference for the output format?

Comment: I meant for creating the date, that has little to do with how your format it when you output it again.

Comment: Hello there @misorude! 
This works for me, but I dont know how to translate the month-names into German:
 
`$todaysmonth = date_i18n('n', strtotime('now')); //reference date
for($i = $todaysmonth; $i <= $todaysmonth+11; $i++)
  {
  $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm', $i );
  $monthName = $dateObj->format('M'); // Month names for list 
  $my_date = $dateObj->format('Y-m-01'); // Date for URL
...´ 

`The $monthName = $dateObj->format('M');´ does not give back German month names and I could not find a way  to translate it. Any ideas?